# Get dataset value from input tag upon click and display as HTML

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the value from the data-price dataset in the radio button after the user has clicked a different option and display it below in the label tag.  I am doing something wrong.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```js
(function (){
    var radios_price = document.getElementById('lbl-011');
    console.log(radios_price.dataset.price);
    for(var i = 0; i < radios_price.length; i++){
        radios_price[i].onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerText = this.value;
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<input id="lbl-011" class="click_radio checkbox123" data-name="One Gel Pen with One Blue Light" name="product_quantity" data-val="2264" data-price="29" data-qty="1" value="1" type="radio">
       
<input id="lbl-011" class="click_radio" data-name="Two Gel Pens and One Blue Light" name="product_quantity" data-val="2263" data-price="39" data-qty="2" value="2" type="radio" checked="checked">
    
<input id="lbl-011" class="click_radio" data-name="Four Gel Pens and One Blue Light with Bonus Mouth Tray" name="product_quantity" data-val="2259" data-qty="4" data-price="49" value="4" type="radio">



<p>Price (data-price):<label id="priceLabel"> $39</label>
```

Comment: First of all, why do you have 3 inputs with the same id? document.getElementById() will only return the first element it finds, as it expects an id to be unique.

Comment: It's invalid syntax to have multiple items with the same `id`. `id` must be unique on the page. Use `class` as a selector instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect all input type with help of classname, call in for loop to access each element.

```js
(function (){
    var radios_price = document.getElementsByClassName('click_radio');
    for(var i = 0; i < radios_price.length; i++){
        radios_price[i].onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerText = "$"+this.dataset.price;
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<input id="lbl-011" class="click_radio checkbox123" data-name="One Gel Pen with One Blue Light" name="product_quantity" data-val="2264" data-price="29" data-qty="1" value="1" type="radio">
       
<input id="lbl-011" class="click_radio" data-name="Two Gel Pens and One Blue Light" name="product_quantity" data-val="2263" data-price="39" data-qty="2" value="2" type="radio" checked="checked">
    
<input id="lbl-011" class="click_radio" data-name="Four Gel Pens and One Blue Light with Bonus Mouth Tray" name="product_quantity" data-val="2259" data-qty="4" data-price="49" value="4" type="radio">



<p>Price (data-price):<label id="priceLabel">$39</label>
```

Comment: I used this because it was closest to what I already had and knew.  Worked very well.  Yes, ID should be unique.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an `id` assigned to more than one element. Lots of tutorials always put a descriptive text as both `id` and `name` attribute, and in the case of radio buttons you do need them all to have the same `name`, but the `id` must be unique to an element.

```js
(function (){
    document.querySelectorAll('#lbl-011 input').forEach((inp) => {
      inp.onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerText = "$" + this.dataset.price;
      };
    });
})();
```

```html
<div id="lbl-011">
  <input class="click_radio checkbox123" data-name="One Gel Pen with One Blue Light" name="product_quantity" data-val="2264" data-price="29" data-qty="1" value="1" type="radio">
       
  <input class="click_radio" data-name="Two Gel Pens and One Blue Light" name="product_quantity" data-val="2263" data-price="39" data-qty="2" value="2" type="radio" checked="checked">
    
  <input class="click_radio" data-name="Four Gel Pens and One Blue Light with Bonus Mouth Tray" name="product_quantity" data-val="2259" data-qty="4" data-price="49" value="4" type="radio">
</div>

<p>Price (data-price): <span id="priceLabel">$39</span>
```

I also turned the `<label>` into a `<span>` and move the whitespace outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, it's important not to assign the same ID to multiple elements. That is what classes are used for.

This is also a good case for taking advantage of event delegation. If you wrap all your input elements in a container you can create an event listener there and respond to whichever radio button was clicked. Doing this you also want to check and ensure that it was actually a radio button that was clicked, and not some other empty space in the parent element.

```js
(function (){
    var inputs = document.getElementById('inputCollection');
    inputs.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      console.log('Collection Clicked');
      if(e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
        // e.target will be the specific input button clicked
        document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerHTML = ' $' +  e.target.dataset.price;
      }
    })
})();
```

```html
<div id="inputCollection">
  <input id="lbl-011" class="click_radio checkbox123" data-name="One Gel Pen with One Blue Light" name="product_quantity" data-val="2264" data-price="29" data-qty="1" value="1" type="radio">

  <input id="lbl-012" class="click_radio" data-name="Two Gel Pens and One Blue Light" name="product_quantity" data-val="2263" data-price="39" data-qty="2" value="2" type="radio" checked="checked">

  <input id="lbl-013" class="click_radio" data-name="Four Gel Pens and One Blue Light with Bonus Mouth Tray" name="product_quantity" data-val="2259" data-qty="4" data-price="49" value="4" type="radio">
</div>

<p>Price (data-price):<label id="priceLabel"> $39</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired output. Like others said, the ID has to be unique. Only the class can be the same.

```
(function() {
  let radios = document.querySelectorAll('.click_radio');

  radios.forEach((radio) => {
    radio.addEventListener('change', () => {

      // This gives you access to all the data attributes you've declared
      //
      let radioData = radio.dataset;

      document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerText = `$${ radioData.price }`
    })
  })
})()
```